# Convert binary string to hex string with leading zeroes in Rust

Tags: rust

> Editor's note: This code example is from a version of Rust prior to 1.0 and is not syntactically valid Rust 1.0 code. Updated versions of this code produce different errors, but the answers still contain valuable information.

Surely there is a better way to convert binary string to hex string than this?

```
use std::num;

fn to_hex(val: &str, len: uint) {
    println!("Bin: {}", val);
    let mut int_val = 0i;
    for (i,c) in val.chars().enumerate() {      
        if c == '1' {
            int_val += num::pow(2i, i+1)/2;
        }
    }

    let f32_val = int_val as f32;
    let mut hex_val = std::f32::to_str_hex(f32_val).to_string();
    while hex_val.len() != len*2 {
        hex_val = "0".to_string() + hex_val;
    }
    println!("Hex: {} @ {} bytes", hex_val, len);
}

fn main() {
    let value = "0001111";
    to_hex(value,4);
}
```

The result for this is

```
Bin: 0001111
Hex: 00000078 @ 4 bytes
```

I'm using rustc 0.12.0-nightly

Comment: Why is the binary string reversed? Shouldn't it be `1111000` to match `0x78`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a way to do what you want in a much terser form with [`std::u32::from_str_radix`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u32.html#method.from_str_radix) and the [`format!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.format.html) macro:

```
use std::u32;

fn to_hex(val: &str, len: usize) -> String {
    let n: u32 = u32::from_str_radix(val, 2).unwrap();
    format!("{:01$x}", n, len * 2)
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", to_hex("110011111111101010110010000100", 6))
    // prints 000033feac84
}
```

[The format syntax](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/index.html) may be a little obscure, but `01$x` essentially means that the number must be printed in hexadecimal form padded with zeros up to the length passed as the second (1st with zero-based indexing) argument.