# What is the easiest way to pad a string with 0 to the left?

Tags: rust, formatting, string-formatting, number-formatting

What is the easiest way to pad a string with 0 to the left so that

- "110" = "00000110"
- "11110000" = "11110000"

I have tried to use the `format!` macro but it only pads to the right with space:

```
format!("{:08}", string);
```

Answer (score 173, accepted):

The [`fmt` module documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/) describes all the formatting options:

> ### [Fill / Alignment](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/#fillalignment)
>
> The fill character is provided normally in conjunction with the
>   `width` parameter. This indicates that if the value being formatted is
>   smaller than `width` some extra characters will be printed around it.
>   The extra characters are specified by `fill`, and the alignment can be
>   one of the following options:
>
> - `<` - the argument is left-aligned in `width` columns
> - `^` - the argument is center-aligned in `width` columns
> - `>` - the argument is right-aligned in `width` columns

---

```
assert_eq!("00000110", format!("{:0>8}", "110"));
//                                |||
//                                ||+-- width
//                                |+--- align
//                                +---- fill
```

See also:

- [How can I 0-pad a number by a variable amount when formatting with std::fmt?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41820818/155423)
- [How do I print an integer in binary with leading zeros?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44690439/155423)
- [Hexadecimal formating with padded zeroes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48972370/155423)
- [Convert binary string to hex string with leading zeroes in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26285550/155423)

Comment: It would be nice to see here succinctly how to specify fill, width, alignment, and the user-specified variable in one go as variables to `format!`

Comment: Is there a way to get width from a variable?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer "The value for the width can also be provided as a usize in the list of parameters by adding a postfix $, indicating that the second argument is a usize specifying the width." — [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.76.0/std/fmt/#width)

Answer (score 25):

As an alternative to Shepmaster's answer, if you are actually starting with a number rather than a string, and you want to display it as binary, the way to format that is:

```
let n: u32 = 0b11110000;
// 0 indicates pad with zeros
// 8 is the target width
// b indicates to format as binary
let formatted = format!("{:08b}", n);
```