# How do I implement String::from for my type?

Tags: rust

I have a type `Clock`:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
pub struct Clock {
    hours: i32,
    minutes: i32,
}
```

Some traits are implemented for it. For example:

```rust
#[allow(clippy::match_bool)]
impl fmt::Display for Clock {
    fn fmt(&self, formatter: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        let tmp = match (self.hours < 10, self.minutes < 10) {
            (false, false) => ("", self.hours, "", self.minutes),
            (false, true) => ("", self.hours, "0", self.minutes),
            (true, false) => ("0", self.hours, "", self.minutes),
            (true, true) => ("0", self.hours, "0", self.minutes),
        };
        write!(
            formatter,
            "{}",
            format!("{}{}:{}{}", tmp.0, tmp.1, tmp.2, tmp.3)
        )
    }
}
```

I want to implement `String::from(Clock::new(...))`. How can I do it?

I've attempted:

```
impl convert::From<Clock> for String {
    fn from(clock: Clock) -> String {
        clock.to_string()
    }
}
```

Comment: Also: [What is the easiest way to pad a string with 0 to the left?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50458253/155423) — `write!(formatter, "{:02}:{:02}", self.hours, self.minutes)`

Comment: [The code you have in your question **works**](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0d52d2b3dfbb0fe24dace863139ebf18). What are you attempting to ask us?

Comment: @Shepmaster, thanks. I decided working solution by myself after asking question.

Answer (score -1):

The working solution:

```rust
impl From<Clock> for String {
    fn from(clock: Clock) -> String {
        clock.to_string()
    }
}

impl fmt::Display for Clock {
    fn fmt(&self, formatter: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(
            formatter,
            "{}",
            format!("{:02}:{:02}", self.hours, self.minutes)
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not `write!(formatter, "{:2}:{:2}", self.hours, self.minutes)`?

Comment: Specifically, using `format!` causes unneeded memory allocation. Also, didn't you want zero-padded numbers?