# How to convert decimal to 16 bit binary in Rust with leading zero

Tags: rust

Is there a way to convert a decimal to a 16-bit binary in Rust using the standard library?

I have this sample:

```rust
let x: u16 = 21;
println!("{}",format!("{:b}", x)); // output: 10101
```

but I need it to include the leading zeroes. like: `21` to `0000000000010101`

I could create a function to add the leading zeroes but I was wondering if I'm missing something in its standard library.

Here are the methods from the std on u16 primitive type: https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.u16.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the easiest way to pad a string with 0 to the left?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50458144/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-pad-a-string-with-0-to-the-left) Particularly the second answer is almost directly what you want, except 16 instead of 8

Comment: Check: https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fmt/index.html - `{:016b}` should do it.